# Trying to get row by row data from a csv file but fs.watch is not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv, stream

i am trying to get row by row data from a csv file, i want to observe changes in my file and get updated data (update means adding rows to file), so below is the code i tried to do it, its working fine till printing rows but not working from fs.watch file code

i am getting  event after change in the file but rows are not transformed

UPDATE :

Is there a way to get data using index value like i know row number and i want to get data of that row and transform and print it

node.js:

```
var csv = require('csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var str = csv().from.stream(fs.createReadStream('test.csv'))
str.transform( function(row){
  row.unshift(row.pop());
  return row;


})
.on('record', function(row,index){
  console.log('#'+index+' '+JSON.stringify(row));



});

fs.watchFile('test.csv', function (curr, prev) {

 str.transform( function(row){
  row.unshift(row.pop());
  return row;

  }).on('record', function(row,index){
  console.log('#'+index+' '+JSON.stringify(row));
  });
});
```

Comment: Try the `chokidar` package http://davidwalsh.name/node-watch-file

Comment: is there a way that if i specify row number in a file i should get data of that row and i will use that data.

Comment: var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('test.csv', {
   persistent: true
});watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
 console.log('event');
 str.transform( function(row){
  row.unshift(row.pop());
  return row;

  }).on('record', function(row,index){
  console.log('#'+index+' '+JSON.stringify(row));
  });
});

Its not printing rows

Comment: Read Nth line of file in NodeJS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394951/read-nth-line-of-file-in-nodejs