# Read nth line in Node.js without reading entire file

Tags: node.js, file

I'm trying to use Node.js to get a specific line for a binary search in a 48 Million line file, but I don't want to read the entire file to memory. Is there some function that will let me read, say, line 30 million? I'm looking for something like [Python's linecache module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html).

Update for how this is different: I would like to not read the entire file to memory. The question this is identified as a duplicate of reads the entire file to memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Nth line of file in NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394951/read-nth-line-of-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: Yes, but that reads the entire file to memory. I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options), you can use `fs.createReadStream(path[, options])`, where:

> options can include **start** and **end** values to **read a range of bytes** from the file instead of the entire file.

Unfortunately, you have to approximate the desired position/line, but it seems to be no *seek* like function in node js.

**EDIT**

The above solution works well with lines that have fixed length.

New line character is nothing more than a character like all the others, so looking for new lines is like looking for lines that start with the character *a*.
Because of that, if you have lines with variable length, the only viable approach is to load them one at a time in memory and discard those in which you are not interested.

Comment: Any idea how to do that with variable line lengths?

Comment: uhm, no, in such a case I suspect you have to read the file line by line and discard those lines you are not interested in.

Comment: I already have a program that does that. I'm looking for optimization.

Comment: I decided to pad the numbers, and ran a script that added 0s to the front of all the primes so that each line was 16 bytes long, 17 with the newline character

Comment: UTF8 will be garbled, UTF8 is not a fixed length

Answer (score 7):

You should use `readline` module from [Node’s standard library](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html). I deal with 30-40 million rows files in my project and this works great.

If you want to do that in a less verbose manner and don’t mind to use third party dependency use [`nthline` package](https://github.com/BorisChumichev/node-nthline):

```
const nthline = require('nthline')
    , filePath = '/path/to/100-million-rows-file'
    , rowNumber = 42

nthline(rowNumber, filePath)
  .then(line => console.log(line))
```

Comment: After locating the line, how do I edit it? And save the file!

Comment: Under the hood `nthline` ignores the lines until an incrementing cursor reaches the desired one. @boris-chumichev so do you say it is performant enough to deal with milion-line files?