# Method for getting CSV File header

Tags: csv, asynchronous, meteor

I'm trying to get a CSV File Header through a method, but it has a very weird syntax. This is what I tried so far and I understand that I'm not receiving anything because it's working asynchronous. I tried other solutions like `async`, `await` but I really don't have so much experience. I'm also using csv-parser package to get the headers only.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 "file.getHeader"(_id) {
    const future = new Future();

    fs.createReadStream("file.csv")
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("headers", headerList => {
        future.return(headerList[0]);
      })
      .on("error", error => {
        future.return(error);
      });

    return future.wait();
  }
```

If you also have some useful links to help me deal with the problem please paste them here. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "header" in terms of [binary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_%28computing%29) or do you mean the first line of the csv, indicating the names of the columns?

Comment: The first line from the csv file.

Comment: You may check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394951/read-nth-line-of-file-in-nodejs#6401299