# Define a string variable in a NodeJS file by fetching the Nth line from a local text file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following script (*shown below shortened and excerpted with only the relevant segments*) using Nodemailer for NodeJS to e-mail the results of a daily AV scan with a variety of system information embedded.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")l
const os = require("os");
var hostname = os.hostname();
var timestamp = Date.now();

// What I need to fill
function getNthLineOfLogFile() {}
var log-file = getNthLineOfLogFile();

...
...

let message = {
     to: "example@email.com",
     subject: 'AV Update for Today',
     text: 'AV Update' + Date.now(),
     html:
          <b>Date:</b> ${timestamp} <br>
          <b>IP Address:</b> ${ip} <br>
          <b>Hostname:</b> ${hostname} <br>
          <b>Verdict:</b> ${log-file} <br>
```

For the `Verdict: ${log-file}` I need to pull the entire 2nd to last line of a text file that's generated by my AV scan (it will always be the 2nd to last line) with the function `getNthLineOfLogFile()` and save the value of that string to `var log-file`.

The string in the text file looks like "Infected Files: >Number<"

I'm lost as to how to solve this obstacle any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394951/read-nth-line-of-file-in-nodejs

Comment: @BlueWater86 Yes, but how do I use that function to save to a variable?